# Laravel как c бекенда подключиться к WebSocket server (beyondcode)

Tags: laravel, websocket, laravel-8

Есть запущенный WebSocket server - `php artisan websockets:serve`

Клиент Echo прекрасно работает.
Но возникла необходимость с бекенда слать сообщения в сокет. Широковещательные события шлют в конкретные каналы. Пытался подключиться к этому сокету, но возвращает ошибку 404.

Настройки

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => false,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ],
        ],
```

делал коннект и на `ws://127.0.0.1:6001`, и на `ws://localhost:6001`, пробовал разные готовые клиенты (например, ratchet/pawl)

[image: Схема организации связей и маршрута информации]

- Синяя линия - это откуда и как информация должна попадать на внешний WSS
- Красная - как она прилетает WS клиентам от внешнего сервера

---

***Также интересует на какой роут ломится Echo client (тот, который JS). У меня Fiddler не завелся.***

**Каким образом возможно послать сообщение на  WebSocket Server от beyondcode ?**

Comment: `Широковещательные события шлют в конкретные каналы.`. Уточните, что хотите сделать? Отправлять в конкретные каналы? Или у вас вообще не получается отправить из PHP кода сообщения? А как шлете? Очень все запутано и мало информации

Comment: @TotalPusher В каналы все шлется без проблем. 
Мне нужно прокинуть данные в WS сервер со стороны PHP сервера. WS сервер сразу же должен отправить эти данные на внешний WS сервер. А когда получит ответ, обработать его и отправить в нужный канал (это реализовано и работает).

Comment: Не понятно `WS сервер сразу же должен отправить эти данные на внешний WS сервер.`. Почему их два? С пакетом beyondcode и Echo я намучался, так как в документации многие моменты не прописаны, а я делал немного кастомную вещь. Пришлось смотреть сорцы и даже сниффить http трафик. Вот пример как я отправляю публичное бродкаст-сообщение, которое увидят абсолютно все, без авторизации, кто подключен к вебсокету https://gist.github.com/dbfun/b140c1eaa68ba0f4fcebabecfe265195 - тут отдельный канал `tendering` с отдельным типом сообщения `PublicTenderStart`

Comment: Попробуйте сделать по примеру выше. Не получится - напишите в вопросе код, который написали. По конфигу ошибки нельзя найти. Если используется докер - укажите это, там есть один момент

Comment: @TotalPusher, добавил схему. Надеюсь Вы поймете как у меня должны данные проходить от моего http-сервера (синяя стрелка). Сейчас все отображенное на схеме работает, кроме обозначенного синей стрелкой.

Comment: Какую функцию выполняет WS Server который внутри MyServer? Прокси? Или там есть какая-то логика?

Comment: Это не похоже на штатный функционал, поэтому вам нужно смотреть сорцы и дорабатывать под свои потребности. Есть класс StartWebSocketServer, который реализует `artisan websockets:serve`. В нем можно определить кастомные роуты (см `BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Server\Router::webSocket()`), если я правильно понял вашу потребность. Либо переопределить уже сущесвующий механизм - отнаследоваться и доработать.

Comment: WS Server - стандартная логика для Pusher, через него кидаются пуш-уведомления в каналы. Но теперь, помимо этого функционала, нужно еще кидать в него управляющие команды и он должен запрашивать и получать данные с внешнего сокета, а потом уже эти данные обрабатывать и уведомлять нужных клиентов (слать пуш-уведомления в нужные каналы)

Comment: В сорцах есть возможность добавления новых роутов через customRoutes(). Как это работает, я не стал разбираться. Я думаю, нужно сделать так: отнаследоваться от команды запуска сервера веб-сокетов, добавить свой канал, свои роуты, и реализацию. HTTP-сервер будет кидать в этот закрытый канал, WS-сервер - уже во внешний. См в сорцах `$connection->send`. Как создать соединение? См. \Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer::onOpen

Comment: @TotalPusher $connection->send бросает сообщение в канал для клиентов. WS сервер при этом сообщений не получает никаких. Но я зашел со стороны "выстрела" броадкастов и по цепочке вышел на реализацию серверной части Пушера, который в свою очередь дергает курлом роут, а тот уже дергает beyondcode\laravel-websockets\src\HttpApi\Controllers\Controller. И вот этот роут и HttpApi Controller создаются при старте WS, а следовательно они есть его частью. Поэтому я могу создать свой роут и контроллер, в контроллере получить WebSocketHandler (а тут и инстанс WS client) и кинуть данные на внешний сервер.

Comment: Да, бросает в канал клиентов. Поэтому нужно создать новое соединение. См. \Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer::onOpen. В этих дебрях абстракций я не смог понять, где оно создается, чтобы создать своё. `который в свою очередь дергает курлом роут, а тот уже дергает` - да, и поэтому я написал, что если у вас докер, могут быть проблемы, localhost там не прокатывает. Надеюсь что вы разобрались и напишите ответ для будущих поколений :)